# transitionTo doesn't work twice

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state defined as

```
$stateProvider.state('test',{
            url: "test",
            title:"test",
            parent:'main',
            templateUrl:"/partials/test.html",
            controller : function($state) {
                $state.transitionTo('test.introduction');
            }
        })
```

I noticed if I visit the state using a link `<a ui-sref="test">link</a>` transitionTo() works the first time, if I click the second time on this link (so I switch from the state `test.introduction` to `test`) the transitionTo doesn't work. It should 'rebounce' on `test.introduction` again.

More details: `test.introduction` is not a static state, it is injected in `run` stage (with all the other children states of `test`).

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    //$stateProvider
    //[...static states...]
    // *****NOTE 'test' is a static state, its children are not

    $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider;

}]);    
app.run([ '$rootScope','$http', '$urlRouter','testChildrenService'
    function ($rootScope, $http, $urlRouter,testChildrenService)
    {
        testChildrenService
            .then(function(data) {
                angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, key) {
                    $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, {
                        url: value.url,
                        template: value.template,
                        title: value.title,
                        abstract: value.abstract
                    });
                    $urlRouter.sync();
                    $urlRouter.listen();
                });
            });
    }]);
```

Comment: what does the code for `test.introduction` look like?  it's not clear what you are expecting?  were you thinking this was going to transition back to itself?

Comment: is test.introduction a state ?

Comment: more details in question

Comment: what does the state 'test.introduction' look like?  Also why are you using a state that upon linking, goes to another state?  I've not seen this.

Comment: Because I don't like the idea of a menu item linking to `test.introduction`, it's more semantically correct a state `test` in the menu. Also, not sure why but with my async state way to add new states, I have problems with test children states used outside the parent o.o